# Is there a function in xlsxwriter that lets you sort a column?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I was wondering if there was a function in xlsxwriter that lets you sort the contents in the column from greatest to least or least to greatest? thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't. Consider using `xlwings` or `win32com`.

Answer (score 2):

Sorting isn't a feature of the xlsx file format. It is something Excel does at runtime.

So it isn't something XlsxWriter can replicate. A workaround would be to to sort your data using Python before you write it.

Comment: would i use the .sort() function for this?

Comment: Yes or `sorted()` depending on the complexity of your data structures. See [Sorting Mini-HOW TO](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) from the Python Wiki.